# What does it mean by the Alternatives symbol a|z?

Tags: symbols, resolve

The following very simple code

```
Resolve[Exists[{x}, x == 3 &&  a + z < x ]]
```

gives the result

```
(a | z) \[Element] Reals && -3 + a + z < 0
```

What is the meaning of (a|z) in this context? I could not understand the documentation on `Alternatives`. Is it equivalent to the statement that $a, z\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes that's what it means, that both `a` and `z` are elements of the `Reals`. See [Element](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)

Comment: @flinty Thanks! The confusing point is that  the documentation says
" p_1 | p_2| ... is a pattern object that represents any of the patterns Subscript[p, i]. "
I thought that the word "any" of the pattern means that either `a` or `z` is real, not both of them.